Why is job not triggering as expected?
I'm working on a GitHub Actions workflow with several jobs for CI/CD. Some jobs are not being triggered as expected, despite previous jobs completing successfully:

The deploy-env job should start only after all the build jobs (build-x, build-y) have completed (successfully or unsuccessfully). This works fine.
The comment job should be triggered after the deploy-env job has finished.

jobs:
  build-x:
    if: github.event.pull_request.state != 'closed' && contains(github.event.pull_request.labels.*.name, 'deploy')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      # ... steps for building X

  build-y:
    if: github.event.pull_request.state != 'closed' && contains(github.event.pull_request.labels.*.name, 'deploy')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      # ... steps for building Y

  deploy-env:
    if: always()
    needs: [build-x, build-y]
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    steps:
      # ... steps for deploying

  comment:
    if: always() && needs.deploy-env.result != 'skipped'
    needs: [deploy-env]
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    steps:
      # ... steps for commenting

Although the deploy-env completes succesfully, the comment job never runs and it gets skipped. Why is this the case?
